# Realm databease in android return null when i use "findFirst()"

Tags: android, realm

i have one screen that save some data after the user choose one area i save it to the realm after that direct i go to another screen and try to find this saved model

carriageRealm.where(CountryRealm.class).findFirst()

but it retruns empty and crashes in some devices?

```
    Realm carriageRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    carriageRealm.beginTransaction();
    carriageRealm.delete(CurrentAreaRealm.class);
    CurrentAreaRealm currentArea = new CurrentAreaRealm();
    currentArea.setAddress_name(area.getAddress_name());
    currentArea.setArea_id(area.getArea_id());
    currentArea.setLatitude(area.getLatitude());
    currentArea.setLongitude(area.getLongitude());
    carriageRealm.copyToRealm(currentArea);
    carriageRealm.commitTransaction();
    carriageRealm.close();
```

Comment: How do you save the data?

Comment: Realm carriageRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        carriageRealm.beginTransaction();

        carriageRealm.delete(CurrentAreaRealm.class);
        CurrentAreaRealm currentArea = new CurrentAreaRealm();
        currentArea.setAddress_name(area.getAddress_name());
        currentArea.setArea_id(area.getArea_id());
        currentArea.setLatitude(area.getLatitude());
        currentArea.setLongitude(area.getLongitude());
        carriageRealm.copyToRealm(currentArea);
        carriageRealm.commitTransaction();
        carriageRealm.close();

Comment: is it possible after save directly go to another screen the realm did not save the data yet  or the instance not refreshed ?

Comment: If you're querying from the same thread, then starting a new commit transaction will advance the Realm to the latest version (so your new Object should be visible). If you're adding the Object from another thread, then we rely on the Android Looper to deliver the notification, before advancing to the latest version. In this case you can do a `findAll` query and register a listener on it to be notified when an object was added